# Trouble to dismiss MapKit iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6, mapkit

I use this code to create driving mode directions in iOS6:

```
Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];

    if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
        MKMapItem *currentLocationItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
        NSString *Latitude = [[_locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *Longitude = [[_locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1];
        MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([Latitude doubleValue], [Longitude doubleValue]) addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *destinamtionLocItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:place];

        destinamtionLocItem.name = _titleString;

        NSArray *mapItemsArray = @[currentLocationItem, destinamtionLocItem];
        NSDictionary *dictForDirections = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};

        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItemsArray launchOptions:dictForDirections];
}
```

The problem is that the navigationBar is always hidden and any button dismiss the view back to your application. So, How to dismiss the MapKit drivingMode?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood what [openMapsWithItems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MKMapItem/openMapsWithItems%3alaunchOptions%3a) is doing. The user is no longer in your app. You've sent them over to Apple's Map.app. The only way to dismiss it is for the user to press the home button.

Answer (score 0):

@Marckaraujo: i completely  agree with @craig .There is no way back to the aplication once you use driving directions mode from inside your app.You only have to press home button and then come back to where you left in your application.

i too got struck with this issue and searched a lot but this is the final solution only.Home Button.